# autoprefixer breaks trying to parse node-sass sourcemap

Tags: source-maps, postcss, node-sass, npm-scripts, autoprefixer

Here's my directory structure:

```
_build/
  |- postcss.config.js
_src/
  |- sass/
        |-main.scss
css/
  |-main.css
  |-main.css.map
package.json
```

I'm trying to rewrite my workflow using NPM scripts.
I want to:

convert all `.scss` files > css > autoprefix > minify > output to the `css/` folder with sourcemaps.

I'm stuck on the autoprefix stage now.

Here's my package.json

```
{
  "name": "workflow",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1",
    "build:css": "node-sass --source-map true ./_src/sass/ -o ./css",
    "build:autoprefix-css": "postcss --config ./_build/ -m -r ./css"
  },
  "license": "ISC",
  "browserslist": [
    "IE 11",
    "last 3 versions",
    "not IE < 11"
  ],
  "devDependencies": {
    "autoprefixer": "^9.3.1",
    "node-sass": "^4.10.0",
    "postcss": "^7.0.5",
    "postcss-cli": "^6.0.1"
  }
}
```

And here's `postcss.config.js`

```
module.exports = {
  plugins: [
    require('autoprefixer')
  ]
}
```

`node-sass` is correctly outputting `main.css` and `main.css.map`. But `autoprefixer` is giving the error:

```
CssSyntaxError: D:\workflow\css\main.css.map:3:20: Missed semicolon

  1 | {
  2 |   "version": 3,
> 3 |   "file": "main.css",
    |                     ^
  4 |   "sources": [
  5 |           "../_src/sass/main.scss",
```

I've tried using the `--no-map` option for `autoprefixer` but it doesn't have any effect. It seems as though `autoprefixer` is treating the `.map` file as if it were `.css`?

One important requirement is that the script work with multiple separate `.scss` files. Some projects specify separate stylesheets, so I can't hardcode a single `main.scss > main.css` pipeline. I need to automatically take all the `.scss` files in `_src/sass/` and output a `.css` file with sourcemap for each one.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to [RyanZim](https://github.com/RyanZim) at `postcss-cli` for finding the problem. When passing a directory to `postcss` you need to glob specifically for just `.css` files, not the entire directory. The order you pass the input/output to `postcss` seems to make a difference too.

Adding the glob and moving the directory option to the front of command, ie changing:

```
"build:autoprefix-css": "postcss --config ./_build/ -m -r ./css"
```

to

```
"build:autoprefix-css": "postcss -r ./css/*.css --config ./_build/ -m"
```

fixes the issue.

Comment: While this wasn't my exact problem, changing my postcss in my package.json from targeting /* to /*.css finally resolved an issue I'd had for 2 days!! Thanks